# Determine indices of entries in an array that start with a certain string

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

How can I determine the indices of elements in an numpy array that start with a certain string (e.g. using `startswith`)?

Example

Array:

```
test1234
testworld
hello
mynewcar
test5678
```

Now I need the indices where the value starts with `test`. My desired outcome is:

```
[0,1,4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694329/1534017) is the way to go, but just as an alternative, you can also use a list comprehension:

```
a = np.array(['test1234', 'testworld', 'hello', 'mynewcar', 'test5678'])

[i for i, si in enumerate(a) if si.startswith('test')]
```

will give

```
[0, 1, 4]
```

This list you could also convert back to a numpy array:

```
np.array([i for i, si in enumerate(a) if si.startswith('test')])
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`np.char.startswith`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.startswith.html) to get the mask of matches and then `np.flatnonzero` to get the matching indices -

```
np.flatnonzero(np.char.startswith(a, 'test'))
```

Sample run -

```
In [61]: a = np.array(['test1234', 'testworld','hello','mynewcar','test5678'])

In [62]: np.char.startswith(a, 'test')
Out[62]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [63]: np.flatnonzero(np.char.startswith(a, 'test'))
Out[63]: array([0, 1, 4])
```