# Use de startswith function for numbers in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a column vector with number and characters like this:

```
Data
123456
789101
159482
Airplane
Car
Blue
159874
```

I need to filter just the numeric values.

I try to use the `Data.int.startswith` function, but i believe what this function doesn't exist.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you're looking for [numpy.chararray.startswith](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.startswith.html)

Comment: possibly modify this answer to work with numbers [Determine indices of entries in an array that start with a certain string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694099/determine-indices-of-entries-in-an-array-that-start-with-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but if you mean that you want to filter out a list of ints from the string, you can do the following:

```
string = """Data
123456
789101
159482
Airplane
Car
Blue
159874""" #The data you provided

def isInt(s): #returns true if the string is an int
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print( [i for i in string.splitlines() if isInt(i)] ) #Loop through the lines in the string, checking if they are integers.
```

This will return the following list:

```
[123456, 789101, 159482, 159874]
```